# Unity Not loading after installing Nvidia proprietary drivers

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, proprietary

I just got a new Nvidia GTX 650. The huge downside at this point is that whenever I use the open source driver, the computer is ridiculously slow. Whenever I use the proprietary drivers and restart, the desktop wallpaper will load and nothing more. I've tried restarting unity only to get a continuous rolling error. With the CCSM options, unity is enabled, yet nothing appears.

Whenever I'm using proprietary drivers I get a microcode error which happens so quickly that I can't record the number.

Comment: Have you tried: >compiz --replace in the terminal, or alt+f2 I don't have too much experience here, but after reading your question that's what I would try next.

Comment: Whenever I try to restart unity I get a glXQUERYEXTENSIONSTRING is NULL.

Comment: what driver are you using?

Have you tried starting Ubuntu in Unity 2D? This might get you working.

Comment: Unity 2d isn't even a selectable option

Comment: I have found out how to fix the issue.

Comment: Be happy to know what it is

Comment: Yes, me too please?

Answer (score -1):

Run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove fglrx --purge
```